# get literal value of bash variable, without glob expansions or other changes

Tags: bash, variable-expansion

I have a folder with some xml files in it: `1.xml`, `2.xml` and so on.
Then i am doing:

```sh
a=*.xml
echo $a
```

I am getting list of these xml files like this:

```
1.xml 2.xml
```

But then i am doing

```sh
a=*.qwe
echo $a
```

I am getting literal value of a:

```
*.qwe
```

Then I am doing

```
a=ls
echo $a
```

I am also getting literal value of a: `ls`

What should i do with a (how to set it properly or how to print it properly?) to always get its literal value even if i have some files with matching extension in this folder? I want always to have `*.xml` value regardless of files in folder.

Expected behavior: regardless of folder contents, for `a=*.xml` and `a=*.qwe` i'd like to have output - `*.xml`, and `*.qwe`.
For `a=ls` case i dont care about output, it is just an example which i cannot understand.
If i have matching files in folder, i am getting list of files, if there are no matching files - i am getting literal value of mask. But in case of `ls` which should return anything in any case i am getting literal value too.

Comment: Put the \*.xml in quotes and so a="\*.xml"

Comment: Result is the same - list of xml files in folder.

Comment: @RamonSailopal, the quotes are needed on the echo command, not on the assignment.

Comment: my issue is not with assigned values, but with echo output. i always would like to get literal value of a in output

Comment: @markp-fuso, the glob is never expanded at assignment time (when assigning to a scalar variable and not an array); it doesn't matter how many matches exist. The right-hand side of a simple assignment does not undergo string splitting or glob expansion.

Comment: @ilya, ...and that makes the linked duplicate perfectly on-point, does it not?

Comment: By the way, consider switching to `declare -p a` instead of using `echo` at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, it seems linked question have explanation of my issue, but i wasnt able to find it using any of keywords i can imagine before creating my own question.

Comment: @ilya, ...well, that's the point of keeping duplicates around in the knowledgebase -- to add more keywords pointing to a given canonical explanation source. :)

Comment: BTW, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113 for a more in-depth discussion of the (many) ways in which `echo`'s behavior is underspecified and varies between implementations, and thus why `printf` is considered more robust.